# Do container.concatenate(ItemType.function)

Tags: python

Is it possible to get a function object out of a list child which, when called, will apply a specific function to all the items and process them in some way (defined function)?

I need to concatenate the outputs of a single function applied to each one of the elements, but I need to be able to call it with only one parameter, the instance of the list (it will be linked to callbacks).

So basically, how can I do this with the example of the processing being a concatenation:

```
class Aggregator(list):
   def concatenate(self,func):
      return lambda s: [s.func() for s in self]

container = Aggregator()
# append objects
(callback, instance) = container.concatenate(ItemType.functionToApplyToAll), container
```

I'm also open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to concatenate the outputs of a single function applied to each
>   one of the elements, but I need to be able to call it with only one
>   parameter, the instance of the list

I'm not sure I totally understood your question and example, but from this description it seems like you're searching for `map`. 
Basically, it applies a function to each of the elements of a sequence, and returns a list with the results:

```
>>> plusone= lambda x:x+1
>>> print map(plusone, [3,4,5])
[4, 5, 6]
```

If you really want to, you can attach it to a custom container:

```
>>> class MyContainer(list):
...     def plusone(self):
...         return map(plusone, self)
... 
>>> MyContainer([3,4,5]).plusone()
[4, 5, 6]
```

but I'd argue that just calling `map` directly is clearer, since it's explicit

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But can the map() call signature void map(self)? As I said the main requirement is to be used as a callback. I could make a custom class but I'm looking for a less repetitive way since it will be for several itemtypes.

Comment: @MisterMystère I don't understand what you mean by `void map(self)`: is this a C callback? or you meant a function that returns `None`? If it's the later, it doesn't matter at all, python won't complaint if you're expecting a `None` return and get something else (unless you explicitly check...)

Comment: Oops sorry, <anything> signature(self). What I mean is that the function I'm looking for must have only one argument, the instance of the list. Because that function will be called as a callback and this is the expected signature. Map does not seem to have that signature...

Comment: Updated my question (from my phone...)

Comment: @MisterMystère If you need to provide the list instance as an argument, you just pass the method of the class. Note the difference between `MyContainer().plusone` and `MyContainer.plusone` - the first takes 0 arguments, the later takes one.

Comment: Yes, but it involves creating another component for each item type. I was wondering if there was a way to create a container class once, and then use a one-liner to get an accessor for every possible container instance.

Answer (score 0):

If the callable is the first element of the list, you can just pass the first item and the remaining items, respectively, as the arguments to `map`.

```
def f(x):
    return x + 3

my_list = [f, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
map(my_list[0], my_list[1:])
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks like map does not provide me with the accessor signature I need. I updated my post (from my phone, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

All posters most certainly knew this but since I wasn't clear enough to get that answer, I shall post my solution.

No need to create a class, I can create an aggregator accessor just by doing this, which is an example with concatenation of the results:

```
(callback_accessor, instance_object) = ((lambda cont: [i.functionToApply() for i in cont]), container)

#... Call:

value = callback_accessor(instance_object)
```